ElasticSearch increased search latency
We've provisioned an Elastic cluster within the AWS OpenSearch service, and we have a single major index with replication set to 3.
Recently, we've noticed a significant spike in search request serving times, sometimes reaching up to 2 seconds. Upon investigation, we found that a couple of data nodes were experiencing increased search latency. After restarting these nodes, they returned to normal behavior.
Here are a few observations regarding the affected data nodes:

They also experienced increased JVMGCYoungCollectionCount and
JVMGCYoungCollectionTime.
These data nodes utilise AWS EBS gp2 (SSD) disks, and it appears they were running out of IOPS credits available from EBS.

Although restarting the data nodes resolved the issue and they began to function normally again, we're puzzled about how a restart could have addressed the underlying problem. It's worth noting that the ES cluster continued to serve the same traffic during this time.
ES version: 7.1
